# What image format should I use for Safari?

Tags: image, safari

I use the picture tag with different variants of the image.

Code:

```
    <picture>
      <source srcset="img/image_1200.webp 1x, img/image_1200@2x.webp 2x" media="(min-width: 1024px)">
      <source srcset="img/image_968.webp 1x, img/image_968@2x.webp 2x" media="(min-width: 640px)">
      <source srcset="img/image_592.webp 1x, img/image_592@2x.webp 2x" media="(min-width: 480px)">
      <source srcset="img/image_440.webp 1x, img/image_440@2x.webp 2x" media="(min-width: 320px)">
      <source srcset="img/image_320.webp 1x, img/image_320@2x.webp 2x" media="(max-width: 319px)">

      <source srcset="img/image_1200.jpg 1x, img/image_1200@2x.jpg 2x" media="(min-width: 1024px)">
      <source srcset="img/image_968.jpg 1x, img/image_968@2x.jpg 2x" media="(min-width: 640px)">
      <source srcset="img/image_592.jpg 1x, img/image_592@2x.jpg 2x" media="(min-width: 480px)">
      <source srcset="img/image_440.jpg 1x, img/image_440@2x.jpg 2x" media="(min-width: 320px)">
      <img src="img/image_320.jpg" srcset="img/image_320@2x.jpg" alt="image">
    </picture>
```

I want to add an image format for safari. What format might work?
[caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=heif) says, that the heic format is not suitable. Am I missing something, or should I only use jpg / webp for safari?

Answer (score 0):

For safari - JPEG 2000.
Here is a link with [support](https://caniuse.com/?search=jp2).

Comment: Please explain what the link says and how it relates to the question.